# Code to solve quadratically constrained quadratic optimisation problem using FindMinimum is very slow. How do I make it faster?

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, timing

### The problem

I have a quadratically constrained quadratic optimisation problem (QCQP) which takes about 13 seconds to find the optimal solution. I want to iteratively optimise a large number of times (50-100 times) and clearly it will take over 10 minutes to run the same problem 50-100 times (with different initial conditions) but I feel that it can be made faster.

I have narrowed down the reason to FindMinimize being slow at solving QCQPs. Any suggestions on how can I speed things up? I have tried playing with AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal with values like 3 and 3 respectively in particular and they offer significant improvement (more than halved runtime) but since the optimal values are small numbers which later get multiplied by 100 when calculating other quantities, precision and accuracy both seem important and I would like to not compromise there if possible.

### Miniature code with important part intact

I am presenting a very simple version of my code here with small optimisation horizon and other numbers since giving the entire code seems overkill (it is quite long) and one with larger optimisation horizons would require me to supply large ready-made expressions (which would otherwise be calculated by my actual code). **The extremely long expressions are just data I have given so that you can run my code and so that you have an idea of how the constraints and objective function look like.**

```
inputs1 = {u51, u52};
(*the objective function of optimisation problem*)
obj = 1.2326*10^-32 + (-0.6 + u51)^2 + (-0.6 + u52)^2 + (-0.6 + 
      100. u51) (3231.8 (-0.6 + 100. u51) + 
      4.28555 (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100 u52)) + (0. - 753.982 u51 + 
      100 u52) (4.28555 (-0.6 + 100. u51) + 
      3231.8 (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100 u52));

(*some constants to make sure you have all required values to run the
code*)
M = 2;
alpha = 0.2;
hor = 2;
P = {{6.78614, -0.962986, 4.91036, -0.839262, 
    1.84927, -0.218886}, {-0.962986, 1.8242, -1.07876, 
    2.54396, -0.536404, 1.83934}, {4.91036, -1.07876, 
    3.70497, -1.16611, 1.4347, -0.571865}, {-0.839262, 
    2.54396, -1.16611, 3.64699, -0.633915, 
    2.69184}, {1.84927, -0.536404, 1.4347, -0.633915, 
    0.56924, -0.362581}, {-0.218886, 1.83934, -0.571865, 
    2.69184, -0.362581, 2.02307}};

windowfunction = Array[HammingWindow, 2*M + 1, {-1/2, 1/2}];
ga = {{0.0071, -0.0564, 0.00580, 0.0104, 0.00240, -0.0321}}; 
de = {{0.0026}} ;


zetas = {{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 
    0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 
    0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 
    0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 
    0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0.}, {0. + 0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)), 0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 
    0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0. + 0.125 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)), 0., 0., 
    0., 0., 0.}, {0. + 0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
     0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)), 
    0. + 0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)), 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.,
     0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0.}, {0. + 0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)), 0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0.}, {0. + 0.0233016 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
     0.125 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)), 
    0. + 0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)), 0., 0., 0., 
    0.}, {0. - 0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
     0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
     0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)), 
    0. + 0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
     0.25 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)), 
    0. + 0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)), 0., 0., 0.}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0}, {0.0108696 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)), 0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0.}, {0.00372826 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
     0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)), 
    0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)), 0., 0., 0., 
    0.}, {-0.0252429 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
     0.125 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
     0.0233016 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)), 
    0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
     0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)), 
    0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)), 0., 0., 
    0.}, {-0.0117118 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
     0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
     0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) - 
     0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)), 
    0. - 0.0504859 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
     0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
     0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)), 
    0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
     0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)), 
    0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)), 0., 0.}};
outputs = {{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0.}, {0.}, {0. + 
     1. (0. + 100. u51)}, {0. + 
     1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)}, {0. + 
     1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)}, {0. + 
     1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)}, {0. + 
     1. (0. - 0.000346987 u51 + 0.0000464269 u52)}};

(*writing and aggregating constraints of the problem*)
domains = u51 \[Element] Reals && u52 \[Element] Reals;
setcons = {-15, -100} \[VectorLessEqual] {0., 
     0. + 100 u51} \[VectorLessEqual] {15, 100} && -10 <= u51 <= 
    10 && -10 <= u52 <= 10;
terminalcons = (-0.6 + 100. u51) (-0.00308956 + 
       1.35067*10^6 (-0.6 + 100. u51) - 
       2.39084*10^6 (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100 u52)) + 
    1.03986 (0.0224865 - 0.00297113 (-0.6 + 100. u51) + 
       0.00227077 (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100 u52)) + (0. - 753.982 u51 + 
       100 u52) (0.00236128 - 2.39084*10^6 (-0.6 + 100. u51) + 
       5.59947*10^6 (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100 u52)) <= 1;
(*next is the quadratic constraint calculation, which involves the
suspect Do loop*)
speccons = 


    0. + (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) (0. + 
       5.11153*10^-8 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) <= 0.2 && 
  0. + (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) (0. + 
       1.99669*10^-6 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + (0. + 
       0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) (0. + 
       6.78614 (0. + 0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)))) + (0. + 
       1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)) (0. + 
       1.60522*10^-6 (0. + 0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       5.11153*10^-8 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + (0. + 
       0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) (0. + 
       0.00005041 (0. + 0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       1.60522*10^-6 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) <= 0.2 &&
   0. + (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) (0. + 
       6.76*10^-6 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + (0. + 
       1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)) (0. + 
       0.0000100326 (0. + 0.125 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       1.99669*10^-6 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + (0. + 
       0.125 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) (0. + 
       0.00005041 (0. + 0.125 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       0.0000100326 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + (0. + 
       0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) (0. + 
       1.8242 (0. + 0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) - 
       0.962986 (0. + 0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) (0. + 
       0.00318096 (0. + 0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) - 
       0.0000127513 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) - 
       0.00040044 (0. + 0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) (0. - 
       0.0000127513 (0. + 0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       5.11153*10^-8 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
       1.60522*10^-6 (0. + 0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. - 
       0.00040044 (0. + 0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       1.60522*10^-6 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
       0.00005041 (0. + 0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. - 
       0.962986 (0. + 0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       6.78614 (0. + 0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) <= 0.2 &&
   0. + (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) (0. + 
       1.99669*10^-6 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + (0. + 
       1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)) (0. + 
       0.00001846 (0. + 0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       6.76*10^-6 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + (0. + 
       0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) (0. + 
       0.00005041 (0. + 0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       0.00001846 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + (0. + 
       0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) (0. + 
       0.00318096 (0. + 0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) - 
       0.0000796957 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) - 
       0.00040044 (0. + 0.0233016 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.125 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) (0. - 
       0.0000796957 (0. + 0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       1.99669*10^-6 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
       0.0000100326 (0. + 0.0233016 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.125 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       0.0233016 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.125 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. - 
       0.00040044 (0. + 0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       0.0000100326 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
       0.00005041 (0. + 0.0233016 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.125 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) (0. + 
       3.70497 (0. + 0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       4.91036 (0. - 0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       1.07876 (0. + 0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. - 
       0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
       0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. + 
       4.91036 (0. + 0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       6.78614 (0. - 0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       0.962986 (0. + 0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. - 
       0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
       0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. + 
       0.00004118 (0. + 0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       1.60522*10^-6 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) + 
       0.00005041 (0. - 0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       0.00040044 (0. + 0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) (0. + 
       0.00003364 (0. + 0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       1.3113*10^-6 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) + 
       0.00004118 (0. - 0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       0.00032712 (0. + 0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) (0. + 
       1.3113*10^-6 (0. + 0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       5.11153*10^-8 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) + 
       1.60522*10^-6 (0. - 0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       0.0000127513 (0. + 0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.25 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. - 
       0.00032712 (0. + 0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) - 
       0.0000127513 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) - 
       0.00040044 (0. - 0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + 
       0.00318096 (0. + 0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.25 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. - 
       1.07876 (0. + 0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) - 
       0.962986 (0. - 0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + 
       1.8242 (0. + 0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) <= 0.2 && 
  0. + (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) (0. + 
       5.11153*10^-8 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + (0. + 
       1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)) (0. + 
       1.0905*10^-7 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       1.99669*10^-6 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + 
    0.0108696 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) (0. + 
       5.47935*10^-7 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.0000100326 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + (0. + 
       0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) (0. + 
       0.00318096 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) - 
       0.00014664 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) - 
       0.00040044 (0.00372826 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) (0. - 
       0.00014664 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       6.76*10^-6 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
       0.00001846 (0.00372826 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 
             1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0.00372826 (0. + 
          1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. - 
       0.00040044 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       0.00001846 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
       0.00005041 (0.00372826 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) (0. + 
       3.64699 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) - 
       0.839262 (-0.0117118 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) - 
          0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + 
       2.54396 (0. - 0.0504859 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       1.16611 (0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. - 
       0.0504859 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
       0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. + 
       2.54396 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) - 
       0.962986 (-0.0117118 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) - 
          0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + 
       1.8242 (0. - 0.0504859 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       1.07876 (0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.13587 (0. + 
             1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (-0.0252429 (0. + 
          1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.125 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
       0.0233016 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. + 
       0.00004118 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       0.0000100326 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) + 
       0.00005041 (-0.0252429 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.125 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0233016 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       0.00040044 (0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) (0. + 
       0.00003364 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       8.19565*10^-6 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) + 
       0.00004118 (-0.0252429 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.125 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0233016 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       0.00032712 (0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. - 
       0.0504859 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
       0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. - 
       0.00058656 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) - 
       0.0000127513 (0. + 
          1. (0. - 0.000346987 u51 + 0.0000464269 u52)) - 
       0.00040044 (-0.0117118 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) - 
          0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + 
       0.00318096 (0. - 0.0504859 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       0.00032712 (0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) (0. + 
       8.19565*10^-6 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       1.99669*10^-6 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) + 
       0.0000100326 (-0.0252429 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.125 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0233016 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       0.0000796957 (0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       1. (0. - 0.000346987 u51 + 0.0000464269 u52)) (0. + 
       2.3513*10^-6 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       5.11153*10^-8 (0. + 
          1. (0. - 0.000346987 u51 + 0.0000464269 u52)) + 
       1.60522*10^-6 (-0.0117118 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) - 
          0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       0.0000127513 (0. - 0.0504859 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + 
       1.3113*10^-6 (0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. + 
       0.00006032 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       1.3113*10^-6 (0. + 
          1. (0. - 0.000346987 u51 + 0.0000464269 u52)) + 
       0.00004118 (-0.0117118 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) - 
          0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       0.00032712 (0. - 0.0504859 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + 
       0.00003364 (0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.13587 (0. + 
             1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (-0.0117118 (0. + 
          1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
       0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) - 
       0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. + 
       0.00007384 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       1.60522*10^-6 (0. + 
          1. (0. - 0.000346987 u51 + 0.0000464269 u52)) + 
       0.00005041 (-0.0117118 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) - 
          0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       0.00040044 (0. - 0.0504859 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + 
       0.00004118 (0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) (0. + 
       0.00010816 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       2.3513*10^-6 (0. + 
          1. (0. - 0.000346987 u51 + 0.0000464269 u52)) + 
       0.00007384 (-0.0117118 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) - 
          0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       0.00058656 (0. - 0.0504859 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + 
       0.00006032 (0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. - 
       0.00032712 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) - 
       0.0000796957 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) - 
       0.00040044 (-0.0252429 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.125 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0233016 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + 
       0.00318096 (0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (0. + 
       0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. - 
       1.16611 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       4.91036 (-0.0117118 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) - 
          0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       1.07876 (0. - 0.0504859 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + 
       3.70497 (0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.13587 (0. + 
             1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) + (-0.0117118 (0. + 
          1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
       0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
       0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) - 
       0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) (0. - 
       0.839262 (0. + 0.0217391 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51))) + 
       6.78614 (-0.0117118 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.042875 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0679348 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.131326 u51 - 0.0174146 u52)) - 
          0.157768 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) - 
       0.962986 (0. - 0.0504859 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.25 (0. + 1. (0. + 0.98241 u51 - 0.132629 u52)) + 
          0.0466033 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52))) + 
       4.91036 (0. + 0.00745652 (0. + 1. (0. + 100. u51)) + 
          0.13587 (0. + 1. (0. - 753.982 u51 + 100. u52)))) <= 0.2;

(*finally finding the optimal solution*)
constraints = domains && speccons && terminalcons && setcons;
FindMinimum[{obj, constraints}, inputs1, Method -> "InteriorPoint", 
 MaxIterations -> 10000]
```

I am quite tired of this problem to be honest and would be extremely grateful for any suggestions. I have kept MaxIterations as 10000 because for larger optimisation horizon, this was needed to ensure I get an optimal solution satisfying tolerances. It seems though that it doesn't work for this smaller optimisation horizon.

### Update to the question

Update 1: Based on Thorimur's comment and an experiment motivated by it, I have realised that my previous suspect, a Do loop, is not the culprit and hence I have modified this question to ask about how can FindMinimize be made faster (or what are the alternatives of course).

Update 2: Thank you very much for the answers, they all help. I am curious to know if using `ConicOptimization` function or `QuadraticOptimization` be faster than `FindMinimum`? Any comments would be really helpful. I thought along this line because all the answers here give things which speed up the code, but for horizon = 50, things still take quite long and it is practically impossible to post a miniature code here for horizon = 50.

Update 3: This is most likely too much to ask from you but I have uploaded my codes on GitHub [here](https://github.com/npnike10/QCQP) and with this, you can change the variable hor to whatever value you wish. The problem I wish to solve is hor=50 and M=20 and the miniature code I have given in the question (hor=2, M=2) is also derived from the uploaded codes. To run the notebook, all you will have to do is change the directory in `SetDirectory` to wherever you store the two packages (.wl files). In the off-chance you are not aware of this, the .nb file on GitHub looks ugly but upon pasting it in Mathematica, it will interpret the text and display it the way one would expect.

Comment: Removing `Method -> "InteriorPoint"` seems to do the trick! Do you have it there for a reason? (If this works, I'll edit my answer.)

Comment: It does do wonders for horizon = 2 but for some of the larger ones like horizon = 10, the difference is not more than a second :(. Since I was working with larger horizons and the method didn't make a difference, I just left it there but yeah I now see that it has implications.

Comment: Ah, I see. And I'm guessing combining it with `Simplify` (which seems safe, unlike `FullSimplify`) doesn't help? It seemed to halve the time in the given example, but I'm not sure how that generalizes.

Comment: Yea it isn't helping, doesn't scale well I think. It deteriorates the runtime from about 12 seconds to over a minute for horizon = 10.

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately I don't know how to help further with `FindMinimum`; all I can suggest is that since you said you had to do it multiple different times, it might be worth trying to do those in parallel with e.g. `Parallelize` or other parallel functionality (though mathematica's parallelization can be finicky, and might require some extra manual work, e.g. distribution of definitions to the right kernels, ensuring things don't conflict, etc.).

Comment: Making use of `NMinimize[{obj, constraints}, inputs1, 
 Method -> "DifferentialEvolution", MaxIterations -> 10000]`, I obtain error communications.

Comment: @user64494 It does give an error about not being able to find any feasible initial point for me as well, but the code doesn't stop running there and eventually gives an answer very close to one by `FindMinimum`. Any particular reason you chose this method? I avoided `NMinimize` because my problem is convex so I can use the faster `FindMinimum` instead and that would give me global minimizer as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is neither the `Do` loop or the fact that the code is not compiled. (I think `FindMinimum` will try to compile if it can.) The problem seems to be rather that `FindRoot` is not good at handling `VectorLessEqual`. This is a quite new feature and so I was surprised that it existed. Rephrasing the inequality constraints "in the good ol' way" seemed to help:

```
setcons = And @@ Thread[{-15, -100} <= {0., 0. + 100 u51} <= {15, 100}] && -10 <= u51 <= 10 && -10 <= u52 <= 10
simpconstraints = Simplify[speccons && terminalcons && setcons]; 
sol = FindMinimum[{obj, simpconstraints}, inputs1, MaxIterations -> 10000]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

simpconstraints /. sol[[2]]
```

> -100 <= 0. + 100 u51 <= 100 && -10 <= u51 <= 10 && -10 <= u52 <= 10
>
> 0.034588
>
> True
> So this is almost certainly a bug. Please file a bug report at Wolfram Support. By the way, I work with version 12.0.

PS.:

Also specifying the real numbers as domains seems to have complicated things more than it should. IIRC, `FindMinimum` assumes real numbers by default.

Comment: This is amazing! I was also searching for how to get rid of Do loops when defining constraints and `And@@` with `Table` does the work and speeds things up even further. For horizon = 10, the runtime is now 1.4 seconds down from 12 seconds. However, my end problem has horizon = 50 and that takes an eternity even now. Could you please help me with that? My original code is in the question linked to this question so perhaps you would be able to find some culprits there. I use version 12.0 as well. Thank you!

PS: I will file a bug report.

Comment: "However, my end problem has horizon = 50 and that takes an eternity even now. Could you please help me with that?" Maybe. But in the code posted above, `hor` does not do anything. I guess it is supposed to be used somehow to generate `speccons`. So it would be great if you updated your code.

Comment: Umm, my code uses functions from a package I made and the variables which use those functions are literally over 300 rows long so I am not sure if I should copy paste such large matrices here. Instead, would the code given here ( https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/243814/73262) work? I am hoping improvements made there for hor = 2 would be scalable, just like yours in this answer are. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It might be too much to ask but in case you would like to, I have given a GitHub link to where my codes are stored in 'Update 3' of my question. You can then try hor = 50 as well.

Comment: Ah, a github link is a very good idea. I am a bit busy at the moment though. Maybe I'll find some time on the long weekend ahead.

Comment: Okay, I had a look into the git repo. Thank you for creating it. The code there is indeed far more complex than I can understand it in the bit of time I can afford to invest. The issue there is that you try to create lists of constraints that might be very redundant while the `"InteriorPoint"` method employs all of them.

Comment: Moreover and more importantly, you try to handle the constraints in a symbolic way. That is fine for a dozen constraints, but it seems to go awfully wrong here. For example, the expression `speccons` that you generate in the function `optimalinputs1` has a `LeafCount` of 214598213. That's humongous.

Comment: If I had to solve these problems, then I would rephrase the problem into functional form: Instead of an expression for the objective, I would write an efficient function that eats a numerical vector and returns the function value. I would do the same with the derivative. And the same with the equality constraints and the inequality constraints and their derivatives separately. Then I would set up the penalty/barrier formulation myself (see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html#442312913).

Comment: Once the penalty/barrier formulation is set up (with an efficient implemenation of the objective function and its gradient), an unconstrained optimization method of `FindMinimum` can be employed, an the gradient can be specified with the `Gradient` option of `FindMinimum`. Unfortunately, `FindMinimum` does not seem to support a corresponding way to communicate the derivatives of the constraints...

Comment: Sorry, I had some health issues hence the delay in responding. This is very interesting and I will try this out. I am also curious if using a dedicated function like `ConicOptimisation` would be faster than using the unconstrained `FindMinimum` as you have said. Could you please share your thoughts on this?

Comment: Oh, I hope you feel well again! Hm. I do not have any experience with ˋConicOptimizationˋ or any of the other new dedicated optimization tools (ˋQuadraticOptimizationˋ, ˋSemidefiniteOptimizationˋ, etc.) If you. an reformulated your problem into one of these, then they will probably work much better. However, IIRC, they work only with _linear_ objective functions... =/

Comment: Thank you, I do feel well again. This sounds promising, I will give it a try by probably converting the quadratic problem to a linear one using slack variables.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like a good idea!

Answer (score 3):

*Note: I found that this answer doesn't actually work, but I'll leave it here as it provides some insight nonetheless.*

Upon surrounding different sections with `Echo[AbsoluteTiming[...], "section-label", First][[2]]`, your `Do` loop actually seems quite fast (0.002 seconds on my machine). `FindMinimum`, however, takes quite a while. (To test this more easily, simply remove `FindMinimum` and see how long it takes.)

The definition of `speccons` is evaluated once, and then the output is used in `FindMinimum`, so it is not as though we are running the `Do` loop in the definition each time we iterate in `FindMinimum`. `speccons`, as a fully evaluated expression, *is* nonetheless used in the process of `FindMinimum`, though, and it is quite complicated, so we might ask if there's a way to simplify it. And indeed, modifying `constraints` to be

```
constraints = FullSimplify[domains && speccons && terminalcons && setcons];
```

seems to work wonders!

**EDIT:** No it doesn't! `FullSimplify` does not actually preserve truth values when manipulating logical formulae, apparently. It seems `FullSimplify` may actually cause a different minimum to be found. Indeed,

```
constraints = 
  FullSimplify[domains && speccons && terminalcons && setcons];
Simplify[domains && speccons && terminalcons && setcons /. 
  Last@FindMinimum[{obj, constraints}, inputs1, 
    Method -> "InteriorPoint", MaxIterations -> 10000]]
```

shows us that the minimum found with `FullSimplify` actually violates the constraints.

We can check that the resulting constraints are actually equivalent. `Simplify` seems to return unquestionably equivalent constraints, but no speedup, whereas `FullSimplify`'s constraints might be weaker; To see the logical relationships, consider the outputs of

```
Simplify@
 Equivalent[Simplify[domains && speccons && terminalcons && setcons], 
  domains && speccons && terminalcons && setcons]

Simplify@
 Equivalent[FullSimplify[domains && speccons && terminalcons && setcons], 
  domains && speccons && terminalcons && setcons]

Simplify@
 Implies[domains && speccons && terminalcons && setcons, 
  FullSimplify[domains && speccons && terminalcons && setcons]]
```

Comment: Thanks for this piece of work! I will keep this idea handy for future.

Answer (score 3):

This works in 0.25 seconds.

```
zetas=FullSimplify[zetas];
terminalcons=FullSimplify[terminalcons];
speccons=List@@{FullSimplify[speccons]/.(1.0->1)};
setcons={-1.0<=u51<=1.0,-10.0<=u52<=10.0};
FindMinimum[Flatten@{obj, speccons, terminalcons, setcons}, {u51, u52}]
(* {0.660595,{u51->0.00600015,u52->0.04524}} *)
```

Comment: Have you missed out on `-100 <= 0. + 100 u51 <= 100` in setcons? Without it, it does take 0.25 seconds but with it, it takes around 34 seconds for me.

Comment: But these do help even then!

Comment: -100 <= 0.  + 100 u51 <= 100  is equivalent to  -1.0<=u51<=1.0  which I did include.

Comment: Ah sorry, should have noticed that. Also, what is the reason for replacing 1.0 with 1? I am curious because point #1 here (https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/) recommends using floating point numbers.

Comment: Replacing 1.0 with 1 changes 1.0*u51 into u51 which is the same thing and a bit more efficient. If u51 isn't approximate to start it will be converted to one soon after because of all the other approximate numbers. I could have also changes 0.0 to 0 in  terminalcons. As it is terminalcons has (0.0 - 753.982*u51 + 100*u52) when it could be ( -753.982*u51 + 100*u52). Also, since floating point numbers are faster we could change (100*u52) into (100.0*u52).

Comment: FindMinimum uses algebra and stuff like 0.0+1.0*u51 only adds extra steps that don't change the outcome. Replace 0.0 with 0 and 1.0 with 1 and that is simply u51.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
setcons = And @@ Thread[{-15, -100} <= {0., 0. + 100 u51} <={15,100}] && -10 <= u51 <= 10 && -10 <= u52 <= 10
constraints = speccons && terminalcons && setcons;
R = ImplicitRegion[constraints, {u51, u52}];
NArgMin[obj, {u51, u52} \[Element] R]

(* {0.00600015, 0.0452401} *)

RegionPlot[R]
```

[image]

Comment: It works! But whenever I use `inputs1={u51,u52}` and then use `inputs1` instead of `{u51,u52}` in `ImplicitRegion` and `NArgMin`, it does not solve the problem and I need to do this for large horizons. Any idea how to circumvent this?